# Why flutter extensions function not show up on android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I couldn't understand, why function name not showed but if I write full name, no error occours.

Any idea ? By the way, if function is getter, android studio suggest it but other way not working.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `this.denemeB()`?

Comment: @rickimaru thank you, it solves my problem :) By the way, do you know the reason why it is not suggesting while writing like my usage ?

Comment: I don't really know the reason. I tried it in DartPad and its behavior is same as yours.

Comment: @rickimaru okay then we will contine by "this" then :), thank you again :)